# java.util.Calendar getMaximum returns wrong last day

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have to fix some code. And for some reason `Calender.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` returned for June 2019 31 days instead of course 30 days, cause June only has 30 days.

```
public static int getWorkingDaysInMonth(int month, int year) {
    Calendar monthStart = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar monthEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
    monthStart.set(year, month, 1);
    return monthStart.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
```

Now as you can see I replaced `getMaximum()` by `getActualMaximum()`. Now I get for lastday = 30  , so now it's correct. But will it always return the correct last day , I do not want to break anything.

And I called the function the following way:

```
getWorkingDaysInMonth(5, 2019);  // 5 is June
```

Thanks for your review.

Comment: So the real question is "will it always return the correct last day"? Did you try it with different months and years and compared the results?

Comment: Yes. When I use function getActualMaximum it seems to work. I really do not know why getMaximum returned 31 days for June. Also for September it returns wrong value I just figured out. I really do not know why. Try it yourself.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and/or `YearMonth`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 5):

[`Calendar.getMaximum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getMaximum(int)) **returns the maximum amount the field passed has**, which is `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` in your case and that is
31, because no month will have 32 days or more
⇒ the maximum amount of days a month can have in a year
⇒ will always ouptut 31, no matter which month is defined

[`Calendar.getActualMaximum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum(int)) **returns the maximum amount of days a *specified* month** (the one defined in that very instance) **actually has**
⇒ the amount of days the month of this instance has in the year of the instance
⇒ will output different values for different months in different years

> That should mean `Calendar.getActualMaximum()` should work for every month in every year.

I would use `java.time` for this, see the following examples:

**long version with calculation:**

```
public static long getWorkingDaysInMonth(int month, int year) {
    // create a LocalDate that represents the 1st of the given month in the given year
    LocalDate firstOfMonth = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
    // and create one that represents the 1st of the following month
    LocalDate firstOfNextMonth = firstOfMonth.plusMonths(1);
    // return the amount of days between (the second argument is exclusive)
    return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(firstOfMonth, firstOfNextMonth);
}
```

**short versions:**

```
public static long getWorkingDaysInMonth(int month, int year) {
    // directly return the amount of days of the specified month
    return YearMonth.of(year, month).lengthOfMonth();
}
```

or

```
public static long getWorkingDaysInMonth(int month, int year) {
    // directly return the amount of days of the specified month
    return LocalDate.of(year, month, 1).lengthOfMonth();
}
```

**Note:**
No matter which version you have to call it by

```
int amountOfDays = getWorkingDaysInMonth(6, 2019);
```

because in `java.time`, months start at 1, like they do in real life ;-)

Comment: or skip the calculation and go with `return LocalDate.of(year, month, 1).lengthOfMonth();`

Comment: Great :) I didn't want to give an answer as yours was so nice with all the explanations.

Comment: @Scratte you could have done it and would have upvoted ;-) but leaving a comment that adds information is valuable, too! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)):

> `month` – the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

So most probably you have given `6`as the month value (because it is the sixth month in the year), but because month is `0` based July was selected and not June.

And here I suggest using the `java.time` api introduced in Java 8 (which was released in [May 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8)). As it is much nicer and easier to use than the "old" date api